# Adding to widgets a to Listview using the builder doesn't keep state of the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView that you can add more widgets to using a button and ListView.builder. The widgets that I am adding are stateful and is called `Timer`. If I edit the text of a Timer and then try to add another widget, the state gets reset for all the widgets in the ListView.

How would I make it so that the widgets keep their state when adding a new widget? If I print the indexes in the `_builderTimer` method it seems like it is rebuilding every single widget in the ListView instead of tacking a new one on.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Rest and Reps"),
          ),
          body: TimerList(),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[DrawerHeader(child: Text('Timers'))],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class TimerList extends StatefulWidget {
  TimerList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimerListState createState() => _TimerListState();
}

class _TimerListState extends State<TimerList> {
  int timers = 1;

  _addTimer() {
    setState(() {
      timers += 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: this.timers,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => this._buildTimer(index)),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: _addTimer, child: Text("Add Timer")),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Start Workout")),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Pause Timer")),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Reset Current Timer"))
    ]);
  }

  _buildTimer(int timerIndex) {
    //Each row show be a widget. Should have Gif/image of Rxcercise, Excercise name and timer length
    return Timer(
        timerIndex: timerIndex,
        excerciseName: "New Excercise",
        excerciseDuration: new Duration(minutes: 0, seconds: 0));
  }
}

class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  Timer(
      {Key? key,
      required this.timerIndex,
      required this.excerciseName,
      required this.excerciseDuration})
      : super(key: key);

  int timerIndex;
  String excerciseName;
  Duration excerciseDuration;

  @override
  _TimerState createState() => _TimerState();
}

class _TimerState extends State<Timer> {
  //Needs to be stateful so that user can pause timer.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> setExcerciseName(passedInName) async {
      print(passedInName);
      setState(() {
        widget.excerciseName = passedInName;
      });
    }

    return ListTile(
      isThreeLine: true,
      title: Text((widget.timerIndex + 1).toString() +
          " " +
          widget.excerciseName.toString()),
      subtitle: Text('Time left'),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.excerciseName = "mememe";
        });
        _popDialog(context, widget.excerciseName,
            setExcerciseName); //When creating a new timer, have Exercise name as default
      },
    );
  }
}

_popDialog(BuildContext context, String excerciseName,
    Function setExcerciseNameCallback) {
  TextEditingController _excerciseNameController;

  _excerciseNameController =
      TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: excerciseName));
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new SimpleDialog(
            title: TextField(
              controller: _excerciseNameController,
            ),
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 280,
                  height: 280,
                  child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                      mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.ms,
                      onTimerDurationChanged: (newTime) {
                        //newTime is what will set the new duration. newTime is typeof Duration.
                        print(newTime);
                      })),
              new TextButton(
                child: new Text('Save'),
                onPressed: () {
                  //SetState when clicking saved
                  setExcerciseNameCallback(_excerciseNameController.text);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ]);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your example.

1. Every time you call `setState` on the `TimerList` widget, it gets rebuilt. Since you create the Timers in the builder Function of the `ListView.builder`, new instances of `Timer` replace the previous ones.
2. In order to make this work you have to keep the instances in the state of `TimerList` and let the builder re-use those when the widget gets rebuilt. You could use a `List<Timer>` for that.
3. `Timer` is a stateful widget, but you do not keep the data (duration, exercise) in the `TimerState` class, but in the Widget class, where data should be immutable.
4. The `TextEditingController` should not reside inside the dialog function, but in the state of `Timer`, instead. It should also be disposed, when the `Timer` gets disposed. Therefore, the function used to show the dialog should be moved inside the `Timer` widget and manipulate the state of `Timer` directly.
5. You declare the dialog callback function within the `build` method of `Timer`. It should be moved outside and become a method of `Timer`. The `build` function should only return the widget it builds and should not implement any side effects.

I have fixed the example.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Rest and Reps"),
        ),
        body: TimerList(),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(child: Text('Timers')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TimerList extends StatefulWidget {
  TimerList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimerListState createState() => _TimerListState();
}

class _TimerListState extends State<TimerList> {
  List<Timer> timers = [];

  _addTimer() {
    final newIndex = timers.length;
    final newTimer = Timer(
      key: ValueKey(newIndex),
      timerIndex: newIndex,
      excerciseName: "New Excercise",
      excerciseDuration: new Duration(minutes: 0, seconds: 0),
    );

    setState(() {
      timers.add(newTimer);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: timers.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => this._buildTimer(index)),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: _addTimer, child: Text("Add Timer")),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Start Workout")),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Pause Timer")),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Reset Current Timer"))
    ]);
  }

  _buildTimer(int timerIndex) {
    return timers[timerIndex];
  }
}

class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  Timer({
    Key? key,
    required this.timerIndex,
    required this.excerciseName,
    required this.excerciseDuration,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int timerIndex;
  final Duration excerciseDuration;
  final String excerciseName;

  @override
  _TimerState createState() => _TimerState();
}

class _TimerState extends State<Timer> {
  late Duration excerciseDuration;
  late String excerciseName;
  late TextEditingController _excerciseNameController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    excerciseDuration = widget.excerciseDuration;
    excerciseName = widget.excerciseName;
    _excerciseNameController = TextEditingController(text: excerciseName);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _excerciseNameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> updateExcercise() async {
    // call set sate to rebuild the widget
    setState(() {
      excerciseName = _excerciseNameController.text;
    });
  }

  //Needs to be stateful so that user can pause timer.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      isThreeLine: true,
      title: Text(
        (widget.timerIndex + 1).toString() + " " + excerciseName,
      ),
      subtitle: Text('Time left ${excerciseDuration.inSeconds} seconds'),
      onTap: () {
        _showDialog(
          context,
          updateExcercise,
        ); //When creating a new timer, have Exercise name as default
      },
    );
  }

  _showDialog(
    BuildContext context,
    Function updateExcerciseCallback,
  ) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new SimpleDialog(
          title: TextField(
            controller: _excerciseNameController,
          ),
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 280,
              height: 280,
              child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.ms,
                onTimerDurationChanged: (newTime) {
                  excerciseDuration = newTime;
                },
              ),
            ),
            new TextButton(
              child: new Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () {
                //SetState when clicking saved
                updateExcerciseCallback();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time playing with flutter so all of your feedback and explanations really helped me!